# How to install man page for Maven on linux?

Tags: java, linux, maven, manpage

I am using linux(mint mate), and installed maven by download & unzip & config the environment, I could use the `mvn` command.

I want to have `man mvn`, not just `mvn -help`, any tip?

---

**@Update:**

To make the question clear, there is no man page for `mvn`, because I install maven by unzip, so I want to install man page for `mvn`, so that I could use `man mvn` to get help.

Comment: Any tip for what? How to create one? Where to download one?

Comment: @Gimby There is no man page for `mvn` command, I want to install man page for `mvn`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to get the man page for maven is to install maven from `apt-get install maven2`, but the man page is exactly the same as `mvn -help`, so I don't see any use in using the version from the repositories because most of the time is an old version.

http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/mvn/

Comment: Disappointingly, this answer appears to be correct. In an ideal world, Maven would have comprehensive man-pages, like Git. I.e. `man mvn` would provide the Maven man page as it currently does, but `man mvn X` would provide a man page for plugin X. E.g. `man mvn dependency` would provide a man-page describing the goals and options for the [Maven dependency plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/).

Comment: Hm, it looks like at least some Maven plugins do provide help at the CLI, though, albeit not via man-pages. E.g. `mvn compiler:help -Ddetail=true`.

Answer (score 2):

There *is* no man page for Maven. It doesn't exist. There's nothing available to install.

Answer (score 1):

If your download did not include man pages for `mvn` and `mvnDebug`, you can use [help2man](https://www.gnu.org/software/help2man/) to easily generate `mvn.1.gz` and then symlink `mvnDebug.1.gz` to it.

```
# Change INSTALL_HOME to point to your Maven install path.
INSTALL_HOME="/opt/maven/apache-maven-3.8.4"

mkdir "${INSTALL_HOME}/man"
help2man -o "${INSTALL_HOME}/man/mvn.1" "${INSTALL_HOME}/bin/mvn"
gzip "${INSTALL_HOME}/man/mvn.1"
ln -s "${INSTALL_HOME}/man/mvn.1.gz" "${INSTALL_HOME}/man/mvnDebug.1.gz"
```

To bind man page(s) and `mvnDebug` command into the same alternative as `mvn`, just add *slave* options then configure the new alternative:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/mvn" "mvn" "${INSTALL_HOME}/bin/mvn" 500 \
  --slave "/usr/bin/mvnDebug" "mvnDebug" "${INSTALL_HOME}/bin/mvnDebug" \
  --slave "/usr/share/man/man1/mvn.1.gz" "mvn.1.gz" "${INSTALL_HOME}/man/mvn.1.gz" \
  --slave "/usr/share/man/man1/mvnDebug.1.gz" "mvnDebug.1.gz" "${INSTALL_HOME}/man/mvnDebug.1.gz"

sudo update-alternatives --config mvn
```